# Which launch config does the debug button at the top-right with the VS Code Python extension use?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

when I open a .py file in vscode, there's a debug button shown up at the top-right coner of the vscode window.

[image]

I have a multi-root workspace, and one launch config defined. When I start debuging/running with F5 button, the one launch config is automatically selected, and everything works fine. But if I use the debug button at the top-right coner as high-lighted, vscode complains it cannot find the modules imported in the workspace.
What debug/run environment does this button use?

Answer (score 1):

#### If you're using the Python Debugger extension

See https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_85#_github-copilot. Quoting:

> The [Python Debugger](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.debugpy) extension now has a configurable debug option under the **Run** button menu. When you select **Python Debugger: Debug using launch.json** and there is an existing `launch.json` in your workspace, it shows all the available debug configurations that you can pick to start the debugger. If there aren't any configurations, you are prompted to select a debug configuration template to use to create a `launch.json` file for your Python application.

#### If you're not using the Python Debugger extension

I'm pretty sure the Run Python File button invokes the same thing as the `Python: Run Python File in Terminal` command in the command palette, which- if I understand correctly- doesn't use launch configs, and instead uses settings that start with `python.terminal.*`. The current list of those settings at the time of this writing is the following (shown with their default values):

```json
// Activate Python Environment in the current Terminal on load of the Extension.
"python.terminal.activateEnvInCurrentTerminal": false,

// Activate Python Environment in all Terminals created.
"python.terminal.activateEnvironment": true,

// When executing a file in the terminal, whether to use execute in the file's directory, instead of the current open folder.
"python.terminal.executeInFileDir": false,

// When launching a python terminal, whether to focus the cursor on the terminal.
"python.terminal.focusAfterLaunch": false,

// Python launch arguments to use when executing a file in the terminal.
"python.terminal.launchArgs": [],
```

Note: docs on debugging Python can be found here: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging.

Though there is a property in python-type launch configs called "purpose", where you can put "debug-in-terminal" in the array value, which seems to make it so the launch config will apply when use the "debug in terminal" mode of the play button at the top-right of the screen.

Comment: So there isn't a way to run the specific file by using the play button at the top-right? I have `"program": "${workspaceFolder}/main.py"` in the launch.json but that doesn't apply when using the play button at the top-right and I have to change the tab every time before using that button.

Answer (score 0):

> If you're only interested in debugging a Python script, the simplest way is to select the down-arrow next to the run button on the editor and select **Debug Python File in Terminal**.

- https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging#_basic-debugging

---

The triangle button in the upper right corner has multiple options.

[image]

Among them, `Run Python File` and `Debug Python File` are provided by Python extension. `Run Python File` executes the current script in the terminal, and `Debug Python File` debugs the current script.

It should be noted that `Debug Python File` does not use the configuration of ***launch.json***. If you configure ***launch.json*** and want to get the effect, you should use the green triangle button to debug on the **Run and Debug** panel,

[image]

or use the `Strat Debugging` and `Run Without Debugging` under the **Run** menu to debugging or run script .

[image]