# VScode will not recognize my launch.json arguments, how can I fix this?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, debugging

Using Visual Studio Code v1.84.2 on Windows 10.
This is my `launch.json` contents:

```
{
   
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Current File",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "justMyCode": true,
            "args": ["F:\\PRODUCTION Sounds\\"]
        }
    ]
}
```

And my script:

```
import os
import argparse
from sys import argv

print(argv)
def find_audio_files(directory):
    # Define the set of file extensions to look for
    audio_extensions = {'.mp3', '.wav', '.aiff', '.flac', '.aac', '.ogg', '.m4a'}
    audio_files = []

    # Walk through the directory
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(directory):
        for file in files:
            # Check the extension of each file
            if os.path.splitext(file)[1].lower() in audio_extensions:
                # If it's an audio file, add it to the list
                audio_files.append(os.path.join(root, file))
    
    return audio_files

def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
                    prog='audiofinder',
                    description='Finds audio files',
                    epilog='Text at the bottom of help')
    parser.add_argument('directory')
    args = parser.parse_args()
    print(f"Searching directory for audio files: {args.directory}")
    print(f"{find_audio_files(args.directory)}")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

My directory structure looks like this:

```
audiofinder
 .vscode
   launch.json
 audiofinder.py
```

And when I run Python debug in VSC, my program outputs: `audiofinder: error: the following arguments are required: directory`

However, this exact argument works fine when passed manually, and furthermore, I added a print statement at the top as you saw, and no such argument is ever passed to the program when under debug mode using this config.

Comment: how _exactly_ are you running python debug? which button / command palette command / menu item do you use?

Comment: If you want to use the configuration in launch.json, you need [F5 or Ctrl+F5](https://imgur.com/sy7sk6j.png) to execute the script.

Comment: I was clicking the little debug bug icon on top right and selecting "Debug Python File" from the menu.

Comment: that's why I asked. it's just like that. if you want a launch config to be used, then use the Debug View's run button instead. this is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/76375592/11107541 then I think. If the answer there helps you, give it an upvote and then we can close this as a duplicate of it.