# How to run a python script in a docker container in vscode when you click on the "Run" arrow button

Tags: python, python-3.x, docker, visual-studio-code, docker-compose

I've been trying to configure vscode so that when I click on that arrow shaped "run" button on the top right, vscode will then build a docker container if the image doesn't exist, and then run a python script in the docker container. I've been playing with the `launch.json` and `tasks.json` files however I was unsuccessful.
This is what I have:
launch.json:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Docker: Run Python Demo scripts",
            "type": "docker",
            "request": "launch",
            "preLaunchTask": "docker-run",
            "python": {
                "pathMappings": [
                    {
                        "localRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
                        "remoteRoot": "/opt/demos"
                    }
                ],
                "projectType": "general",
                "file": "/opt/demos/${relativeFile}"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

tasks.json

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "docker-build",
            "label": "docker-build",
            "platform": "python",
            "dockerBuild": {
                "tag": "product-demo-scripts:latest",
                "dockerfile": "${workspaceFolder}/Dockerfile",
                "context": "${workspaceFolder}",
                "pull": true
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "docker-run",
            "label": "docker-run",
            "dependsOn": [
                "docker-build"
            ],
            "python": {
                "file": "/opt/demos/${relativeFile}"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

The goal of something like this is for someone who's not technical, they can just open vscode in the directory, click on the run button, and there you have it, the script runs successfully without them having to deal with docker. 
From what I gathered from the docs, and from online sources. This is doable in debugging mode which worked for me, but that's not very presentable. \

I gathered that it doesn't work for regular execution. 
I welcome anyone who was ever successful in achieving anything similar to what I described to contribute to this thread even if it's not with vscode. If you're reading this and reached this point then I wish a very good day. 
Thank you !

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/75547380/11107541 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/76375592/11107541

Comment: Thank you for sending the related threads. However, neither of the threads propose a solution that works for me, they both propose debugging mode which is not suitable.

Comment: the point was to say that looking at the run button at the top right is a bad direction and that it does not use your launch configs or task configs.

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to **Run and Debug** and select `Docker: Python - General`, `Docker: Python - Django`, or `Docker: Python - Flask`, as appropriate.

[image]

You have to use Debug mode instead of clicking Run Python File Button.

You can read [document about docker](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/containers/quickstart-python#_build-run-and-debug-the-container) for more details

Comment: So I know about debug mode, and I tried to achieve what I want using it, but it doesn't work. I was just wondering if it's possible to create a custom run configuration that starts a docker container, and then runs the python file inside the docker container, when I click on  the ">" button